# Why is my aside at the bottom of this page?

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm wondering why my aside is at the bottom of the page instead of next to the main content when I apply (float:right;) in the css. I've tried to float it on the left and the main content on the right but had the same problem.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Photoblog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"/>  
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">  

      <header>
        <h1>Photoblog</h1>
      </header>

      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <article>
        <h2>Welcome:</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus et eros
          justo, quis consectetur arcu.  Etiam vel orci massa, vel vestibulum ante.
          Nam posuere luctus iaculis. In id augue augue. Integer vel massa purus, 
          sit amet tincidunt sapien. Integer sit amet adipiscing risus. 
          Praesent rhoncus mauris mattis justo mattis eget egestas augue 
          interdum. Curabitur tempus accumsan lacus id accumsan. Nulla fermentum, 
          purus a tempus tristique, diam nibh porttitor felis, et aliquet nunc nisl 
          ac turpis.
        </p>    
      </article>

      <article>
        <h2>First Impressions</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus et eros
          justo, quis consectetur arcu.  Etiam vel orci massa, vel vestibulum ante.
          Nam posuere luctus iaculis. In id augue augue. Integer vel massa purus, 
          sit amet tincidunt sapien. Integer sit amet adipiscing risus. 
          Praesent rhoncus mauris mattis justo mattis eget egestas augue 
          interdum. Curabitur tempus accumsan lacus id accumsan. Nulla fermentum, 
          purus a tempus tristique, diam nibh porttitor felis, et aliquet nunc nisl 
          ac turpis.
        </p>        
      </article>

      <article>
        <h2>Bro</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus et eros
          justo, quis consectetur arcu.  Etiam vel orci massa, vel vestibulum ante.
          Nam posuere luctus iaculis. In id augue augue. Integer vel massa purus, 
          sit amet tincidunt sapien. Integer sit amet adipiscing risus. 
          Praesent rhoncus mauris mattis justo mattis eget egestas augue 
          interdum. Curabitur tempus accumsan lacus id accumsan. Nulla fermentum, 
          purus a tempus tristique, diam nibh porttitor felis, et aliquet nunc nisl 
          ac turpis.
        </p>            
      </article>

      <aside>
        <h2>About Me</h2>
        <p>
          Hello here is some placeholder text. Hello here is some placeholder text.
          Hello here is some placeholder text. Hello here is some placeholder text.
          Hello here is some placeholder text. Hello here is some placeholder text.
        </p>
      </aside>

      <footer>
        <p>By Howard Tang</p>
      </footer>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #F2E9E1;
    color : #111111;
    font-family : "Arial", "helvetica", sans-serif;
    font-size : 11pt;
}

header h1 {
    background-color: black;
    padding:0px;
    color: #ffffff;
    display:block;
    height: 80px;
    width: 960px;
    text-align : center;
    line-height:80px ;
    font-family : "Georgia", Serif;
}

nav ul {
    list-style : none;
    width:960px;
    padding : 0;
    text-align : center;
}

nav ul li {
    color : #111111;
    display : block;
}

nav {
    display : block;
}

nav a {
    color : #111111;
}

nav ul li {
    display : inline;
}

article {
    float : left;
    width : 600px;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-right : 20px;
    padding-left : 20px;
    padding-bottom : 40px;
    background-color : #cbe86b;
}

article img {
    height : 400px;
    width : 600px;
}

aside {
    padding-left: 20px;
    float: right;
    background-color : #cccccc;
    width : 300px;
}

#container {
    width : 900px;
    margin : 0 auto;
}

footer {
    margin-top: 20px;
    float : left;
    text-align: left;
    width : 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't accounted for the padding in your widths. If you reduce your widths to those below, the `aside` will move back to the side.

```
article {
    background-color: #CBE86B;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 20px 40px;
    width: 560px; /* 560px + 20px + 20px = 600px */
}

aside {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    float: right;
    padding-left: 20px;
    width: 280px; /* 280px + 20px = 300px */
}
```

Comment: This is exactly right. For more info, the OP may want to read about the [box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html).

Comment: Right I see, I had a feeling it might be something to do with this so I already tried making the width of the aside smaller which didn't seem to work. However you seem to have fixed the issue by accounting for it within the article. Now I guess the next question is how to position the two so that the are horizontally aligned?

Comment: @howard: Easiest way is just to  move your `aside` to be above the `article`s in the html. http://jsfiddle.net/JGN3K/3/.

Comment: Thanks for the help tw, of course i'll accept the answer. I was just wondering how the order of divisions in html affects their position on screen. I'd have thought good practice would ignore the order that it is marked up in.